# Guardar ruta de fichero mediante tkinter en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy usando tkinter para guardar la ruta de un archivo que se seleccione mediante un botón. Luego quiero que esa ruta se muestre en un Label para ver si es correcta o no. No consigo guardar en una variable fuera de la función esta ruta. Este es el código que tengo.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Planificacion Semanal")
root.resizable(1,1)
root.geometry('500x300')
var = tk.StringVar()
ruta = tk.StringVar()

def abrirArchivo():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Selecciona el export JIRA",filetypes = (("Ficheros excel","*.xlsx"),("Macros","*.xlsm"),("All files","*.*")))
    var.set(file)
    ruta = file.name

file = Button(root, text="Archivo JIRA", command=abrirArchivo).place(x=10,y=10)
labelJIRA = Entry(root, textvariable=ruta).place(x=10,y=40)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido Darío c:

## Solución

Antes de darte un código, hay algunas cosas por aclarar:

1- Las variables de control (en tu caso, StringVars) no son como las variables comunes de Python. Para cambiar el valor que se guarda en un StringVar hay que usar el método set.

2- `filedialog.askopenfilename` en si te devuelve la ruta y el nombre del archivo en forma de cadena. No hace falta ni se puede hacer `file.name`.

3- En el código que pasaste, el StringVar `var` no tiene ningún proposito. Por lo que no se que piensas hacer con él.

4- No es un Label, es un Entry.

Aquí abajo te dejo la forma correcta de darle valor al "label" teniendo en cuenta los puntos 1 y 2.

```
def abrirArchivo():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Selecciona el export JIRA",filetypes = (("Ficheros excel","*.xlsx"),("Macros","*.xlsm"),("All files","*.*")))
    var.set(file)
    ruta.set(file)
```

## Bonus

[tu widget].place devuelve siempre None, por lo que el valor que tienen `file` y `labelJIRA` es None. Digamos que hacer estas lineas:

```
file = Button(root, text="Archivo JIRA", command=abrirArchivo).place(x=10,y=10)
labelJIRA = Entry(root, textvariable=ruta).place(x=10,y=40)
```

Guarda el mismo valor en las variables que:

```
file = None
labelJIRA = None
```

Para evitar esto, lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear el widget y luego ubicarlo en líneas de código diferentes. Por ejemplo así:

```
file = Button(root, text="Archivo JIRA", command=abrirArchivo)
file.place(x=10,y=10)

labelJIRA = Entry(root, textvariable=ruta)
labelJIRA.place(x=10,y=40)
```

Este es un error muy común entre los que recién empiezan a usar Tkinter.